# copying files from one directory to another

Tags: files, directory, cp

I have to copy a set of files from one folder to another folder and I'm using the following command:

```
cp -rf `head -n 100 /home/tmp/abc.txt` /home/tmp/test/files
```

the file contents in `abc.txt` is like:

```
./folder1/example.tar.gz
./folder2/example.tar.gz
./folder3/example.tar.gz
```

But while executing the above `cp` command I'm getting:

```
cp: will not overwrite just-created `/home/tmp/test/files/example.tar.gz' with `./folder3 /example.tar.gz'
cp: will not overwrite just-created `/home/tmp/test/files/example.tar.gz' with `./folder1/example.tar.gz'
```

I can understand that because the name of the .gz files are the same that are showing in the error. What I want to do is to have the same folder structure inside `/home/tmp/test/files` as listed in `abc.txt`, like:

```
/home/tmp/test/files/folder1/example.tar.gz
/home/tmp/test/files/folder2/example.tar.gz
/home/tmp/test/files/folder3/example.tar.gz
```

But I'm getting only one `example.tar.gz` inside files folder after executing the above `cp` command.

So what is the way to get what I mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### cp won't work

Your example as it stands will not work because copy doesn't copy directory structures, it will only copy the files, hence the error message you're encountering. To do a deep copy such as this you can enlist either the `tar` command and use the construct `tar cvf - --files-from=... | (cd /home/tmp/test/files/; tar xvf -)` or you can just use `rsync`.

#### rsync

If I were you I'd use `rsync` to do this like so:

```
$ rsync -avz --files-from=abc.txt /src /home/tmp/test/files/.
```

If you only want the 1st 100 lines from file `abc.txt` you can do this:

```
$ rsync -avz --files-from=<(head -n 100 abc.txt) /src /home/tmp/test/files/.
```

#### Example

Sample folder data:

```
$ tree /home/saml/tmp/folder*
/home/saml/tmp/folder1
`-- example.tar.gz
/home/saml/tmp/folder2
`-- example.tar.gz
/home/saml/tmp/folder3
`-- example.tar.gz
```

Now copy the files:

```
$ rsync -avz --files-from=<(head -n 3 /home/saml/tmp/abc.txt) \
         /home/saml/tmp/. /home/saml/tmp/test/files/.
building file list ... done
./
folder1/
folder1/example.tar.gz
folder2/
folder2/example.tar.gz
folder3/
folder3/example.tar.gz

sent 3147093 bytes  received 81 bytes  6294348.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3145728  speedup is 1.00
```

Confirm they were copied:

```
$ tree /home/saml/tmp/test/files
/home/saml/tmp/test/files
|-- folder1
|   `-- example.tar.gz
|-- folder2
|   `-- example.tar.gz
`-- folder3
    `-- example.tar.gz
```

#### tar

If you interested here's how you do it using just `tar`.

```
$ cd /home/saml/tmp
$ tar cvf - --files-from=<(head -n 3 /home/saml/tmp/abc.txt) | (cd /home/saml/tmp/test/files/; tar xvf -)
./folder1/example.tar.gz
./folder1/example.tar.gz
./folder2/example.tar.gz
./folder2/example.tar.gz
./folder3/example.tar.gz
./folder3/example.tar.gz
```

Confirm that it copied:

```
$ tree /home/saml/tmp/test/files
/home/saml/tmp/test/files
|-- folder1
|   `-- example.tar.gz
|-- folder2
|   `-- example.tar.gz
`-- folder3
    `-- example.tar.gz
```

Comment: but in my case i am using the head command to copy only a certain number of files, so my command is like 
$ rsync -avz  `head -n 100 /home/tmp/abc.txt` /home/tmp/test/. /home/tmp/test/files                                        This also copies only one example.tar.gz to the destination folder.what is wrong in this or how to use files-from in this command?

Comment: @user1752557 - you can use your `head` command as input to the `--files-from=` list. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @user1752557 - see updates.

Comment: Can you please tell me the version of linux which supports rsync

Comment: @user1752557 - any versions typically support it. It may not be installed but depending on the distros' package manager (apt, yum, etc.) it can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most certainly not that `cp` doesn't copy directory structures. Of course it does: `cp -r` (recursive).

What `cp`, at least POSIX `cp`, doesn't do is re-create the relative paths of the source operands in the destination directory.

If you `cp a/b/file1 a/b/file2 a/c/file3 dest` then you get `dest/file1 dest/file2 dest/file3`.

If your `cp` is the one from GNU Coreutils, it may have the `--parents` option. Not sure when that was introduced. `cp --parents` will induce GNU `cp` into producing this path re-creation mechanism. From the Info documentation:

```
--parents
  Form the name of each destination file by appending to the target
  directory a slash and the specified name of the source file.  The
  last argument given to `cp' must be the name of an existing
  directory.  For example, the command:

      cp --parents a/b/c existing_dir

  copies the file `a/b/c' to `existing_dir/a/b/c', creating any
  missing intermediate directories.
```

So if you have GNU `cp`, the only change you need is to drop the `-r` since we are not recursing, and use `--parents`:

```
cp --parents -f `head -n 100 /home/tmp/abc.txt` /home/tmp/test/files
```